# How can I project a shape onto environment/VBO?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am working on a real time strategy game and I need to draw the selection rectangle on my cubic voxel based terrain, how can I do that? I am aware that some RTSs simply get away with simple 2d/hud/gui/on screen method, but I really do like how Warcraft 3 does that on terrain.

Guys, this isn't about picking , this is about rendering a rectangle, on an uneven surface of multiple different blocks. Similar how the grid is rendered in Warcraft 3: World editor!
http://press2reset.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Warcraft3WorldEditorScreen.jpg

Comment: Google for "3d picking".

Comment: @GregPrisament: Picking has nothing to do with projecting stuff onto terrain.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I agree there are multiple approaches to this and picking might not be the best, but I do think it is possible.  Here's what I was thinking: You could potentially use picking to determine the "on click" terrain cell, as well as the "mouse over" terrain cell.  Then render the rectangular region bounded by those two cells in a different color, or whatever.

Comment: I can already pick the 2 points for the 2 corners of the box, I don't know how to render it though! Also I just realized warcraft doesn't have that, it's World Editor does though

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma: Not sure I understand the problem.  Are you saying you know how to render a 3D terrain, and know the terrain grid cell bounds of you selection?  In that case, just render the cells inside your selection differently, and they'll look "selected".  Please clarify if I'm missing something.

Comment: @GregPrisament I need to render a hollow rectangle kinda like I'd do with glBegin(GL_LINES) and draw the four lines, but i need them to draw on top of the terrain. I'm not selecting the cells of the terrain, I just need to draw the rectangle similarly to how the grids are in this image: [W3:WE](http://press2reset.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Warcraft3WorldEditorScreen.jpg)

Comment: @NicolBolas picking is deprecated and emulated by the driver, he should write his own raycasting stuff or use a library for this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find the screen space of the of the 3d space you are selecting.

If that is the case then "picking" will find the 3d point you clicked on, then do the normal `MVP * pickedPoint` to get into clip space, divide by `w` and finally multiply by your window width and height, i.e.:

```
vec4 clipSpacePt = ModelviewProjection * pickedPoint
clipSpacePt.xyz /= clipSpacePt.w;

vec2 windowSpacePt;
windowSpacePt.x = clipSpacePt.x * windowWidth;
windowSpacePt.y = clipSpacePt.y * windowHeight;
```

Do that for the first picked point and also for where your cursor is at to get your "projected selection rectangle".